# Regex to match any "UNUSED" rules in CSS (class, id, etc)

Tags: css, regex, code-cleanup

I have a huge CSS file which I want to trim down to only used css rules.

I did this by using [CSS Usage Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/) for Firebug. It adds an "UNUSED" label to every rule not being used. Now I want to get rid of these.

The CSS code looks like this:

```
body {
line-height: 1;
text-align: left;
}
UNUSED.multiple-list {
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 1.4;
list-style: disc;
margin-left: 20px
}

UNUSEDmenu, UNUSEDol, ul {
list-style: none
}
UNUSEDblockquote, UNUSEDq {
quotes: none
}
```

I tried to find my own Regex using RegExr online service but I was only able to select the part in between the curly braces.

My Regular expression so far:

```
\{([^}]+)\}
```

How can I modify the expression to select anything from "UNUSED" to the closing curly brace? But only if things start with "UNUSED"? All other rules should not be marked.

Answer (score 4):

**This Regex will match any UNUSED attribute:** `UNUSED.*\{[^}]*\}|UNUSED.*[}]*`

The first part of the regex matches any UNUSED attribute that includes a block, and the second part of the regex (after the `|`) matches any UNUSED attribute that does not include a block - so you're totally covered.
It will match classes, id's, blocks, single lines - every UNUSED attribute.

[RegExr test](http://regexr.com?31t9q)

---

**** [jdlx's regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15318650/1380370) is a bit more complex but it's better and safer. Take a look at it.***

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much. Now things also start to get a bit clearer to me ;) Note: You need to enable "global" but disable "dotall" to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

**amiregelz**'s regex [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11918357/668767) will match rules with *valid* selectors.. thus break the CSS.
Here's my2¢ on regexing it :

Step 1 - match whole **rules** with *only* unused selectors and remove the whole rule:

`(?<=}|/)\s*(UNUSED[.#:<>\+\w\d\s_-]+)(,\s*UNUSED[.#:<>\+\w\d\s_-]+)*\{[^\}]+}`

Step 2 - match all unused **selectors** on rules that do have valid/used selectors:

`(UNUSED[.#:<>\+\w\d\s_-]+,\s)|(,\s*UNUSED[.#:<>\+\w\d\s_-]+)`

RegExr Tests: [Step 1](http://regexr.com?342kg) - [Step 2](http://regexr.com?342km)

hth